# Show that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{f_{n-1}\,f_{n+1}} = 1$ by the telescoping technique

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

[image]

I'm not sure how to approach or set this up. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
f_{n+1} = f_{n}+f_{n-1} \rightarrow f_{n} = f_{n+1}-f_{n-1}\\
\frac{1}{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}} = \left(\frac{1}{f_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{f_{n+1}}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{f_n}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{f_{n}f_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{f_{n+1}f_{n}}\right) = \frac{1}{1\cdot 1} = 1
$$

Comment: clearly $f_n \to \infty$ when $n\to \infty$ (apply$ f_n = c_1 \varphi_1^n + c_1\varphi_2^n$) or just realize is increasing (unbounded) by definition